# Do I need multiple Views for multiple ViewHelpers?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, view-helpers

In my application I have **one** `View` class. It gets instantiated and injected into a controller which does something like

```
$this->view->load('sometemplate')
```

and then outside the controller at a later stage I do

```
$view->render();
```

It does what I need but recently I have came across `ViewHelpers` and I like the idea of encapsulating presentation logic.

The problem is I would have multiple `ViewHelpers` and I don't want my single `View` to hold them all individually like

```
private $orderHelper;
private $feedbackHelper;
....
```

or

```
private $helpers = array();
```

Would it make sense to have a different `View` for each page like

```
class Feedback extends View {
    private $feedbackHelper;
}
```

or is there a better way of achieving this?

Another way I was thinking was that the `View` has a `HelperFactory` which I can use to create whichever `Helper` I need from any page.

What would be the best way to implement these helpers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As layman that I am:

Creating different View classes just for the purpose to handle multiple Helpers doesn't make sense (Don't Repeat Yourself unnecessarily).

Creating a HelperFactory as a method doesn't make sense, 'cause if you want to create your Helper Object *dynamically*, you'll still have to pass or execute a "new Helper"-statement to this method, not? So why not call it dependency injection and let your controller inject your View with one or more Helpers...

```
class Controller {
    this->view->inject(new ViewHelper($args));
}
```

...and let your View put'em in the helper[] (why not?)...

```
class View {
    private $helper;

    public function inject($dependency) {
        $key = lcfirst(get_class($dependency));
        $this->helper[$key] = $dependency;
    }

    public function getHelper($key) {
        return $this->helper[$key];
    }
}
```

Your helpers would be accessible via your View.

*Nonetheless I'm curious too, what others think about it.*

One step beyond this solution might be using a **dependency injection container**.

These are interesting and pretty understandable **links**:

- http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection
- http://r.je/mvc-php-router-dependency-injection.html